# How can I model convection in a simple and effective way?

Tags: thermodynamics, simulations, diffusion, heat-conduction

I have a project in which we're trying to model heating of a room. We are modelling the room in 3D. 
The room has realistic walls, windows and a door, which will loose heat through them. To balance the heat loss, we want an oven to heat the room. The oven is a panel oven with a given wattage.

We are currently using the explicit finite differece method on the heat equation,
$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\alpha \nabla ^2T$ 
When using a constant thermal diffusivity ($\alpha$), we find that the heat more or less doesn't leave the area around the ovens. 
When using a temperature-dependent thermal diffuisivity, we find that the temperature explodes, more or less. (We have more than triples checked that the units match)
But when looking at the standard deviation of the normal distribution of the heat diffusion,
$\Delta x^2 = 6\alpha t => \Delta x = \sqrt{6\alpha t}$ 
the heat cannot expand all the way in the time intervals we are looking at. Source for equation is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion). 
Say we are running our simulation for 60 minutes, using $\alpha = 19*10^{-6}$, then $\Delta x \approx 0.64 m$. And the box in which the heat has spread to is $(2\Delta x)^3 \approx (2*0.64)^3 m^3$ (well, a sphere with radius 0.64m)

We are modelling our room to be $2 \times 2\times 2 m^3$. If we are using one oven, with a wattage of 2000 W, and assume for simplicity that the heat evenly distributes, 
$\Delta T = \frac{Q}{\rho V c} = \frac{2000W * 3600s}{1.2 \frac{kg}{m^3} \times 8 m^3 \times 1012 \frac{J}{kg K}}= 741 K$ 
The volume in our model in which the heat actually distributes, is equal or less than this. 
Now, our code shows that the oven and the air in immediate proximity will in fact become very hot (1500 K or more). 
(We have initial temperature inside of 20 degrees celsius, and the outside temperature is constantly -20 degrees celsius.)
But further out in the room, the temperature will be very cold (5 degrees celsius). As the simulation runs for one hour, this is obviously wrong.
But, since diffusion is a slow process, this is what would be expected for our model.

I think we are missing the contribution from convection. As this is a time-limited project, our professor told us it would be too complicated to model convection as well. Therefore I am wondering if there is a way we can increase the thermal diffusivity to make our model at least more realistic than it is now? 
In our project, we want to answer which heating strategy over night, will cost less. Therefore it is essential to have a realisitic model. However, as I have understood, convection spreads out $\propto t$, while diffusion spreads out $\propto \sqrt{t}$. We would obviously have to discuss this in our projectreport.

Comment: I think that you have understood pretty much the problem and the possible solutions. Basically you are neglecting convection, which is the most relevant process for heat transfer in this context. Convection moves hot air rather quickly away from the source, leaving cold air close to it, making heating more efficient than with simple diffusion.
You can increase $\alpha$ rather arbitrarily to finish your project quickly, but a thorough discussion of the problem would need modeling convection.

Comment: One more thing. I really appreciate this project, but I would switch the question to "how can I model convection in a simple and effective way?", which you don't need for your project, but I think would lead to fruitful discussion in the answers.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that!